# Applied Bayesian Statistics - Textbooks

Tags: bayesian, inference, references, causality

I understand the bayesian statistics, but I don't see many textbooks approaching the bayesian statistics in a practical way. Some book recommendations on Bayesian Practical Applications would be great. Something like how to apply the bayesian methods in different scenarios like

1. Experimentation - A/B testing
2. Predictive analytics
3. Causal inference
4. Any other Modelling

etc

with practical examples

Comment: See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=gelman+bayes*+reference+book)

Comment: There are many books on practical Bayesian Analysis. Search for books by Authors : Kruschke, Stone, Downey, Lambert, Cowles, Pearl. Stanton, Gelman-Rubin.